# Error in Taylor's polynomials

Tags: calculus

I'm having trouble trying to understand how I would go about finding out the degree of the taylor polynomial required to provide accuracy to the specified range. Would I use the error equation to help me achieve this or is there another way?

If f(x) = ln(x) and Pn(x) is the n-th order Taylor polynomial for f at a = 1, how large must n be to be certain that Pn(1.1) approximates ln(1.1) to within 5 × 10−8?

Comment: In this case, the series we get is an *alternating series*, so the absolute value of the error when we truncate at the $n$-th term is less in absolute value than the first "neglected" term. For alternating series, this is an easier and more useful estimate than the Lagrange form of the remainder.

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the forms of the remainder in a truncated Taylor series. The Lagrange form for the remainder on the closed interval from $a$ to $x$ is:
$$
R_k(x)=\frac{f^{(k+1)}(\xi)}{(k+1)!}(x-a)^{k+1}
$$
for some $\xi$ between $a$ and $x$.

So you need to find a $k$ such that the remainder $R_k(1.1)$ for the $k$-th order Taylor polynomial for $\ln(x)$ about $a=1$ is less than $5\times 10^{-8}$

Alternatively; observe that the Taylor series for $\ln(x)$ about $a=1$ at $x=1.1$ is an alternating series and so the absolute value of the error in a truncated series is bounded by the absolute value of the first neglected term.

Answer (score 0):

As you already made it, setting $x=y+1$ Taylor expansion of $\log(x)$ around $x=1$ is the same as Taylor expansion of $\log(1+y)$ around $y=0$ that is to say $$P_n(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i-1}\frac{(x-1)^i}{i}$$ n and, as explained in previous answers and comments, the first neglected term will be (in absolute value) $$R_k(x)=\frac{(x-1)^k}{k}$$ So, you want $k$ such that $$\frac{a^k}{k} \leq \epsilon$$ (for your case $a=0.1$ and $\epsilon=5 \times 10^{-8}$).

You could be interested by the fact that the solution of $\frac{a^k}{k}=\epsilon$ is given by $$k=-\frac{W\left(-\frac{\log (a)}{\epsilon }\right)}{\log (a)}$$ in which appears  Lambert function, the value of which being possibly estimated using quite good approximations (have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Using for example $$W(z)=L_1-L_2+\frac{L2}{L1}$$ with $L_1=\log(z)$ and $L_2=\log(L_1)$, for your particular case this would lead to $k=6.48$ so $7$ terms should be used.

You can check that $R_6(1.1)= 1.66667\times10^{-7}$ and $R_7(1.1)=1.42857\times10^{-8}$.